# Is using a main() function to get rid of global variables best practice?

Tags: python, global-variables, program-entry-point, local-variables

I just started learning python recently.  I was having issues with having global variables that I didn't want. Below is a small portion of my code that shows two variables *phrase* and *picture* that are global variables being used in my functions.

```py
    # Lets the user input a phrase for the players to guess
    def choose_phrase():
        phrase = input("Type a phrase: ")

        valid_response = False
        while not valid_response:
            for character in phrase:
                valid_response = True
                if not character.isalpha() and character != ' ':
                    valid_response = False
                    phrase = input("Type a phrase with only letters and spaces: ")
                    break

        return phrase


    # This declares the ascii art in list: 'picture'. It will also add the blank letter spaces showing 
    # the players how many letters and words the phrase is. It also has a mechanism for wrapping the 
    # output for easier viewing.When wrapping, this code will produce more items in 'picture' to support 
    # more lines.
    def create_initial_picture():
        picture = [...]
        count = 1
        line = 19
        for character in phrase:
            if (character == ' ') & (count > 25):
                additional_lines = ["", "", ""]
                picture.extend(additional_lines)
                line += 3
                count = 1
            elif character == ' ':
                picture[line] = picture[line] + "    "
            else:
                picture[line] = picture[line] + "___ "
            count += 1
        return picture


    phrase = choose_phrase()
    picture = create_initial_picture()
```

I did not like having the global variables so I tried to emulate the main function from other languages to fix this problem and my code then looked like this:

```py
    def main():
        phrase = choose_phrase()
        picture = create_initial_picture(phrase)

    # Lets the user input a phrase for the players to guess
    def choose_phrase():
        phrase = input("Type a phrase: ")

        valid_response = False
        while not valid_response:
            for character in phrase:
                valid_response = True
                if not character.isalpha() and character != ' ':
                    valid_response = False
                    phrase = input("Type a phrase with only letters and spaces: ")
                    break

        return phrase


    # This declares the ascii art in list: 'picture'. It will also add the blank letter spaces showing 
    # the players how many letters and words the phrase is. It also has a mechanism for wrapping the  
    # output for easier viewing. When wrapping, this code will produce more items in 'picture' to support 
    # more lines.
    def create_initial_picture(phrase):
        picture = [...]
        count = 1
        line = 19
        for character in phrase:
            if (character == ' ') & (count > 25):
                additional_lines = ["", "", ""]
                picture.extend(additional_lines)
                line += 3
                count = 1
            elif character == ' ':
                picture[line] = picture[line] + "    "
            else:
                picture[line] = picture[line] + "___ "
            count += 1
        return picture


    main()
```

This accomplishes getting rid of the global variables, but I am not sure if this is orthodox or considered best practice.  I am big about trying to make good habits early on and do not want to continue this method if it will lead me into bigger problems down the line.  Any feedback on this would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are the global variables causing a problem? If you don’t want them hanging around after you are done you could alway delete them with `del phrase` for example.

Comment: there's not much between the two,  having two variables scoped at module level vs two scoped in `main()` function.  A common use of `main()` pattern is in conjunction with `if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()` so that code works same from command line or can be invoked by another module when imported

Comment: @DanielButler It didn't necessarily create errors. It just made me either have to structure my code in a weird and unintuitive way or change variable names in functions to be different than the global variable names which made things confusing, to be honest.

Comment: @Rob Raymond Thanks. I'm going to look into `if __name__ == '__main__':     main()`.